# How can I make empty grayscale image in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to know how to make a empty grayscale image in OpenCV.

First, I know how to make a empty 'color image' like this.

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np
blank_image = np.zeros((height,width,3), dtype = np.uint8)
```

Then, how can I make a empty 'grayscale' image with specific height and width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
gray_image = np.full((height, width), gray_value, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np
gray_level = 127
gray_image = gray_level * np.ones((height,width,3), dtype = np.uint8)
```

If you don't need 3 channels, make that `np.ones((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)`